# how to find nearest occurence of recurring event with google calendar api

Tags: events, google-calendar-api

[Time of occurence of a Google calendar recurring event (Python API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145977/time-of-occurence-of-a-google-calendar-recurring-event-python-api)
my problem is kind of the same, but the solution is not good for me, because I don't need all other recurrences of that same event, I need only one nearest to today. I don't think its smart to use singleEvents=true in my case because of traffic and processing of unnecessary data. so the only choice what i'm left with is try to find nearest event by recurrence rule. or am I missing something? maybe somebody have solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am doing using the c# api :

```
evtQuery.SingleEvents = true;
evtQuery.SortOrder = CalendarSortOrder.ascending;
evtQuery.ExtraParameters = "orderby=starttime";
evtQuery.StartTime = start;
evtQuery.EndTime = end;
evtFeed = calSvc.Query(evtQuery);
```

start and end are set with +-1 day from now.

Then, when browsing evtFeed, if I don't get what I am searching, I am doing a new request with start and end set with +-5 Days.